# How do you tell the difference between a left shift and a right shift of a periodic function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why does the horizontal phase shift of:

$
2\sin(-3x-\frac\pi2)
$

shift to the right instead of to the left?

I am expecting this for 
$
2\sin(-3x-\frac\pi2)
$
:
[image]

I'm instead getting this for 
$
2\sin(-3x-\frac\pi2)
$
when using a graphing utility:
[image]

I get the first graph by turning

$
2\sin(-3x-\frac\pi2)
$

into

$
2\sin(-3x+\frac\pi2)
$

However, because of the -3x, wouldn't the resulted sign be flipped from it's original sign, if I remove the negative in front of the -3x, I still get the 2nd graph. Why is this?

Comment: I did not get the second graph when I graphed $f(x)=2\sin (-3x+\frac{pi}{2})$. Can you also add equations for the graphs in your photo?

Comment: Fixed it, what I meant was that I got the first graph from graphing $2\sin(-3x+\frac\pi2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true for the graph of any function $f$ of $x$: in order to shift it to the right by $a$ units, you have to *subtract* $a$ from $x$, i.e., the shifted graph is the graph of $f(x-a)$.

To see why this might be so, you might think of it this way: Shifting the graph to the right by $a$ units is equivalent to shifting the $y$-axis by the same amount to the left. Shifting the $y$-axis like this effectively adds $a$ to all of the old $x$ coordinates, i.e., $x' = x+a$. To get the expression for the same graph using these new $x'$ coordinates, you have to solve for $x$ and substitute into the original expression, thus $f(x)$ gets transformed into $f(x'-a)$.

Another way to remember that you *subtract* to shift right, consider the graph of the line $x=k$. (This isn’t the graph of a function of $x$, but that’s not really important.) If you shift this line to the right by $a$, you obviously get the line $x=k+a$, which we can also write as $x-a=k$.

Comment: This did it. Much appreciated.